# A bit complex C2102: '&' requires l-value error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, lvalue

I'm trying to compile a old C++ code (Eudora Mail) on Visual Studio 2017 and I'm getting about 400 C2102 errors.

The code is very similar in all the cases:

```
        const CSummary *&       GetPrev(POSITION& rPosition) const
                            { return reinterpret_cast<const CSummary *&>( m_ObList.GetPrev(rPosition) ); }  // Error C2102
```

<afxcoll.inl>

```
    _AFXCOLL_INLINE const CObject* CObList::GetPrev(POSITION& rPosition) const // return *Position--
{ CNode* pNode = (CNode*) rPosition;
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidAddress(pNode, sizeof(CNode)));
    if( pNode == NULL )
        AfxThrowInvalidArgException();
    rPosition = (POSITION) pNode->pPrev;
    return pNode->data; }
```

Can anyone help me to find a easy way to solve them ?

Thank you in advance

Ronald

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:[Compiler Error C2102](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2102?view=msvc-160)

> The address-of operator ( & ) must have an l-value as operand.

The errors comes because you're getting adress of a temporary:

```
m_ObList.GetPrev(rPosition)
```

which is a **non-const** pointer of type `const CObject*`.

One cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to temporary.

If you want to return a pointer you can remove &:

```
 CSummary* GetPrev(POSITION& rPosition) const
 { return static_cast<const CSummary *>( m_ObList.GetPrev(rPosition) ); }
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I need to find a easy way to solve it (through a tmp variable?) cause I have to replicate it more than 400 times ... :-(

Comment: Changed done, but now I get a C2440 Error: cannot convert from 'const CSummary *' to 'const CSummary * &'

Comment: It seems you are converting pointers to references. However, I cannot judge the problem based on the existing information. If you could provide a minimal example, it will help solve the problem. Also, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [C2440](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440?view=msvc-160).

Answer (score 0):

I've changed:

```
const CSummary*& GetHead() const
                            { return reinterpret_cast<const CSummary *&>( m_ObList.GetHead() ); }
```

To:

```
const CSummary*& GetHead() const
{
    const CObject* tmp;
    tmp = m_ObList.GetHead();
    return reinterpret_cast<const CSummary *&>(tmp);}
```

m_ObList.GetHead is something like this:

```
    _AFXCOLL_INLINE const CObject* CObList::GetHead() const
{ ASSERT(m_pNodeHead != NULL);
    return m_pNodeHead->data; }
```

So I got no compiler errors, but I'm not sure if it is what it should be